# Get LinearLayout reference at custom view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

My question is about Android/Java.

I wanna access to other views from my custom view.

My main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout1">

    <org.javaforum.input
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        required=""
        android:hint="Enter your E-Mail"
        oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('SO - Please enter a correct E-Mail!!!')"/>

    <org.javaforum.input
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        inputType="submit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So when the second "input" view is clicked, I wanna check if there exists an attribute named "required" at the first "input" view.

I tried this in my input.java:

```
public class input extends TextView{
    public input(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr, getIdentifier(context,attr));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout1);
                View v = null;
                for(int i=0; i<layout.getChildCount(); i++) {//Error
                    //Code
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.LinearLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
```

I don't understand why it's null. It should be already created, right?

So how can I get an LinearLayout reference of my main.xml at my custom view correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the null pointer exception, you will need to search for the other widget in the parent *LinearLayout*. You can use [View.getParent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getParent()) to identify the parent. Since the view you are looking for is a sibling of the current view, you will find it in the parent.

As for determining if a certain attribute is set, I recommend that the value be captured by its view and a method provided to present that value upon request. Say the value is your "required" value then capture that value locally and provide a method, `getRequiredValue()`, for instance, to expose it.

Comment: are there the same to provide a method and provide a variable to get the "required" value?

Comment: @Button Since the "required" value is something that you have defined and is therefore a custom attribute you will have some work to do to define and retrieve its value from the XML. See [Define Custom Attributes](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr).

Comment: I extracted the "required" attribute from the AttributeSet object. But I got a problem. Maybe I will need to ask another question regards to this issue...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getRootView().findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout1);
```

if you only call `findViewById` inside custom view it only lookup the child view.

Comment: lol incredible what a little bit inline modification can change in the whole app...

Comment: But I should recommend you take a look @Cheticamp solution, it only find the parent view instead of find the root view and find the parent view again. in case you want find another id and it's not parent view my solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

This should be called in the Activity's onCreate instead of TextView's onFinishInflate.

First give the submit button an id eg btn_submit, then in onCreate

```
    Button btn_submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout1);
            View v = null;
            for(int i=0; i<layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                //Code
            }
        }
    });
```